# Navigation bar doesn't collapse on click with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium. In a website When I click on the navigation menu from the browser it opens up. But I couldn't open it with selenium webdriver.

Here is the source HTML Sample:

```
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse np" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-1">
                                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                                <span class="icon-filter"></span>
                                                                Quick Filters
                                                            </a>
                                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                <li class="row">
                                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                                                                <label class="nmt">
                                                                                    Category
                                                                                </label>
                                                                                <input type="hidden" id="hidJobCategory" value="-1" />

                                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                        <div class="radio">
                                                                                            <label for="CategoryType1">
                                                                                                <input type="radio" checked name="CategoryType" id="CategoryType1" value="F" onclick="loadCatgory(this.value)"><!--loadCatgory(this.value)-->
                                                                                                Functional Category
                                                                                            </label>
                                                                                            <label for="CategoryType2">
                                                                                                <input type="radio"  name="CategoryType" id="CategoryType2" value="B" onclick="loadCatgory(this.value)" ><!--loadCatgory(this.value)-->
                                                                                                Special Skilled Category
                                                                                            </label>
                                                                                        </div>

                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
```

I tried this:

```
foo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"]/ul/li[1]/a')
foo.click()
```

It didn't work. It redirects to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a hyperlink you can also try:

```
driver. find_element_by_link_text('Quick Filters').click();
```

Not sure if you need to hover over the hyperlink before you click on it. If yes, then probably you will have to hover over it before clicking using the WebDriver Actions class.